# Sorting this Object by Name...

Tags: javascript

```
var addObjectResponse = [{
    'SPO2': '222.00000',
    'VitalGroupID': 1152,
    'Temperature': 36.6666666666667,
    'DateTimeTaken': '/Date(1301494335000-0400)/',
    'UserID': 1,
    'Height': 182.88,
    'UserName': 'Admin',
    'BloodPressureDiastolic': 80,
    'Weight': 100909.090909091,
    'TemperatureMethod': 'Oral',
    'Resprate': 111,
    'HeartRate': 111,
    'BloodPressurePosition': 'Standing',
    'VitalSite': 'Popliteal',
    'VitalID': 1135,
    'Laterality': 'Right',
    'HeartRateRegularity': 'Regular',
    'HeadCircumference': '',
    'BloodPressureSystolic': 120,
    'CuffSize': 'XL',
}];
```

How can i sort this object by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES5 solution, which is available in all 'Major' browsers:

```
Object.keys( addObjectResponse[0] ).sort().forEach(function( key ) {
    console.log( key, ': ', addObjectResponse[0][key] );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that your `addObjectResponse` array contains more than one element, and you wish to sort these elements according to their `UserName` property.

First, you need a function that compares names. It returns "0" when the two names are the same, "1" when the second name should be after the first, and "-1" when the second name should be before the first. A bad example would be:

```
function compare(a,b) { 
  if (a < b) return 1; 
  if (a > b) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

This example is bad because you probably want to sort in a case-insensitive way, or based on last name then first name, but it will work.

Once you have your comparison function, you can use the `sort()` member function:

```
addObjectResponse.sort(function(a,b) { return compare(a.UserName, b.userName) });
```

Then, your array will be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript guarantees no ordering of object properties (keys) you'll need to maintain your own array of their ordering which you can then iterate to get the corresponding properties in sorted order:

```
function getSortedKeys(o) {
  var ns=[], i;
  for (i in o) { ns.push(i); }
  return ns.sort();
}

var sortedKeys = getSortedKeys(addObjectResponse[0]);
sortedKeys; // => ["BloodPressureDiastolic", "BloodPressurePosition", "BloodPressureSystolic", "CuffSize", ...
```